# Sails js Query builder

Tags: jquery, mysql, sails.js

how I can user query builder? I need to create query

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, count(c.id) 
FROM parent p 
JOIN child c ON c.parent_id=p.id 
WHERE <criteria>
GROUP BY p.id
```

I want something like

```
var query = 'SELECT p.id, p.name, count(c.id) FROM parent p JOIN child c ON c.parent_id=p.id ' +
     where(request.where) +
     skip(request.skip) +
     limit(request.limit) +
     ' GROUP BY p.id'
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that, since according to the sails.js documentation, it does not have anything to match a group by clause.

Comment: @Shadow Sails have a native query method - but I don't want to parse where, limit etc because this already done in Sails. I just want to use it outside the Model, get string and concat it with my custom `select` and `group` clauses